# How to extract a subset of a bitset larger than unsigned long long without using to_string or extracting bits one-by-one?

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I want to extract a subset from a given bitset, where:

1. both **G**(given bitset size) and **S**(subset size) are known at compile-time
2. **G** **`>`** `sizeof(unsigned long long) * 8`
3. **S** **`<=`** `sizeof(int) * 8`
4. The subset may start anywhere in the given bitset
5. The resulting subset *should* be a bitset of the correct size, **S**

---

I can isolate the subset using bitwise math but then `bitset.to_ullong` does not work because of overflow error.

I know I can use `bitset.to_string` and do string manipulations/conversion. What I'm currently doing is extracting bits one-by-one manually *(this is enough for my use case)*.

I'm just interested to know if there are other ways of doing this.

Comment: Would shifting and masking work?  Something like `bitset >>= subset_start_bit; bitset &= std::bitset<N>(subset_mask); bitset.to_ullong();`?

Comment: No since the `&` operator is only defined for bitsets of the same size.

Comment: You create a new bitset for the mask that is the proper type (size) so that the operator can work.

Comment: But then that would cause an overflow when calling `to_ullong`.

Answer (score 2):

`std::bitset` has bitshift operators, so for example you can write a function to place bits `(begin,end]` at the front:

```
template <size_t size>
std::bitset<size> extract_bits(std::bitset<size> x,int begin, int end) {
    (x >>= (size-end)) <<= (size-end);
    x <<= begin;
    return x;
}
```

For example to get the bits 1 and 2:

```
int main()
{
    std::bitset<6> x{12};
    std::cout << x << "\n";

    std::cout << extract_bits(x,1,3);
}
```

Output:

```
001100
010000
```

If you know `begin` and `end` at compile-time you can get a `std::bitset` containing only the desired bits:

```
template <size_t begin,size_t end,size_t in>
std::bitset<end-begin> crop(const std::bitset<in>& x) {
    return std::bitset<end-begin>{ x.to_string().substr(begin,end-begin) };
};

auto c = crop<1,3>(x);
std::cout << c;        // 01
```

If the bitset is too large to fit in a `unsigned long long` I don't know another way that does not use `to_string()` or loops for individual bits.

Comment: This method will still return a subset with the same size as the original bitset. But I need a subset with the correct size. Using your example, I want to be able to get a bitset of size 2. *(I'll edit my question in case it was not clear enough)*

Comment: @SacrificerXY see edit. When you know the position and size at compile time you can get a smaller bitset, I just wouldnt know how to do it without `to_string` or manually iterating over the bits